# conditional merging of two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables called user, with the fileds user.userID and user.lastActivityTime, and session with the same fields. Now i want to get an user by ID but if there is an entry in the sessionTable with the same userID i want to get all from user but the lastActivityTime from session. How can I do this?

Thank You

Comment: do you want the result placed on one of these tables? or you just need to show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN session ON user.UserID=session.UserID`

And use `session.lastActivityTime` preferentially if it is not null.

Comment: but i want to use this in WHERE and ORDER BY too, how can i do this?

Comment: @Chris: You can do a WHERE restriction and an ordering on either side of the join.  Read up on SQL JOIN syntax.